# C# Windows Form output a sentence with values on a label box

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently making a windows form in Visual Studio that can convert celsius to fahrenheit and vice versa. I have all the input and processing done, but I can't figure out how to output the answer to a blank label box. I need it to come out as "userInput celsius is calculatedFahrenheit fahrenheit"

I've tried using the standard "{0} degrees celsius is {1} degrees fahrenheit". userInput, calculatedFahrenheit. but this doesnt work, i've tried using + userinput, but this also is throwing errors.

Comment: `label1.Text = $"{userinput} degrees celsius is {calculatedFahrenheit} degrees fahrenheit";`

Comment: that did it, thank you! I think my issue was forgetting the $

Answer (score 1):

Use `.Concat` method:

```
label1.txt = ((string)userinput).Concat(" degrees celsius is ").Concat((string)calculatedFahrenheit).Concat(" degrees fahrenheit.");
```

Or you can use the String Interpolation:

```
label1.Text = $"{userinput} degrees celsius is {calculatedFahrenheit} degrees fahrenheit";
```

Remember, if your variables aren't string but objects then use the `.toString()` method

```
userInput = userInput.toString();
calculatedFahrenheit = calculatedFahrenheit.toString();
```

Or when it are numbers use `string.valueOf(userInput)` or `string.valueOf(calculatedFahrenheit)`

Here is a nice documentation about strings in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/